# fabric.js loading a SVG as an object

Tags: svg, fabricjs

Im currently working with fabric.js and am attempting to load a SVG and have similar functionality as i do currently with rectangles (which i used to test)

What i can currently do is create a 
box1.on('moving', function()
{
  movetobox(box1a, box1)
});

to move a second rect(im refering to their objects as box1a and box1) to always be ontop of another.

But if i load a SVG, i am getting an undefined error when trying to refer to it using a on('moving').

i have created a JSfiddle to show my code easier

https://jsfiddle.net/marak/5tvdu532/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=5tvdu532

now this works for rects:

```
box1.on('moving', function() {
  movetobox(box1a, box1)
});
```

but this doesnt work for SVG's

```
box1SVG.on('moving', function() {
  moveSVGtobox();
});
```

(note both functions do the same thing, their on the JSFiddle).

Is there another way to load in a SVG that allows me to reference it the same as a rect?  Im going to have quite a few of them, and each has to be able to align with different objects and be accessable through code.

- Marak

Comment: BTW that SVG wont show up in JSfiddle, i cant find a hot-linkable SVG at the moment (im using localhost for testing).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

Inside of the creation script for the SVG i added this: name="test"

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://localhost/pgl/images/marakrough.svg', function(objects, options) { 
    var shape = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.add(shape.scale(1));
    shape.set({ left: 200, top: 100, name: "test" }).setCoords();
    canvas.add(shape);
```

this allowed me to build an array later of all objects on the canvas after i have added them using this:

```
var objs = canvas.getObjects();
```

and search through that for any with a name of test which i then assigned to another variable.

```
var testOb = objs[1];
```

this i was able to make direct modifications on with no issues (so far)

```
testOb.left += 1;
```

Im not sure if this is HOW its supposeto be used, but by 5am, im just happy its working.

Cheers,
Marak